# How can I convert an image received through socket.io into an image in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I have a node.js server with socket.io communicating with a Unity application. A user can draw an image using Canvas on any browser and send it to other sockets (currently using toDataUrl). This sends an image in text which i can put into another browser and it will be able to represent it as an image.

**The issue I am having is that I can't convert this so that it can appear on a SpriteRenderer in Unity.**

I am able to get an image appearing through a regular URL using img.texture but currently the data isn't in a format that I understand how to work with.

How an image is sent through javascript:

photo: canvas.toDataURL()

**Should I try using a different method to send the image other than toDataUrl?**

**An example of a string that I need to convert into a sprite renderer:
(Copy and paste the whole thing into a browser and a smiley face should appear)**

> data:image/png;base64,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

Edit with all code currently:

> public string url = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAcIAAAHCCAYAAAB8GMlFAAAgAElEQVR4Xu2dC5xdVX3vf+tMklLUmvoCvSrEzElAIXOGZM4EaDGpFCuoCH7UW3wRq1j0qvj6aO29Eq5921Zs0frmoVjFgg+waKskgJjMmSRzJiKYnAmgKELUCteKEGbOup+VnNEhzGOvffbeZ6+9v/vzmc8E5r/+j+9/zfnN3nvttY04IAABCEAAAiUmYEpcO6VDAAIQgAAEhBAyCSAAAQhAoNQEEMJSt5/iIQABCEAAIWQOQAACEIBAqQkghKVuP8VDAAIQgABCyByAAAQgAIFSE0AIS91+iocABCAAAYSQOQABCEAAAqUmgBCWuv0UDwEIQAACCCFzAAIQgAAESk0AISx1+ykeAhCAAAQQQuYABCAAAQiUmgBCWOr2UzwEIAABCCCEzAEIQAACECg1AYSw1O2neAhAAAIQQAiZAxCAAAQgUGoCCGGp20/xEIAABCCAEDIHIAABCECg1AQQwlK3n+IhAAEIQAAhZA5AAAIQgECpCSCEpW4/xUMAAhCAAELIHIAABCAAgVITQAhL3X6KhwAEIAABhJA5AAEIQAACpSaAEJa6/RQPAQhAAAIIIXMAAhCAAARKTQAhLHX7KR4CEIAABBBC5gAEIAABCJSaAEJY6vZTPAQgAAEIIITMAQhAAAIQKDUBhLDU7ad4CEAAAhBACJkDEIAABCBQagIIYanbT/EQgAAEIIAQMgcgAAEIQKDUBBDCUref4iEAAQhAACFkDkAAAhCAQKkJIISlbj/FQwACEIAAQsgcgAAEIACBUhNACEvdfoqHAAQgAAGEkDkAAQhAAAKlJoAQlrr9FA8BCEAAAgghcwACEIAABEpNACEsdfspHgIQgAAEEELmAAQgAAEIlJoAQljq9lM8BCAAAQgghMwBCEAAAhAoNQGEsNTtp3gIQAACEEAImQMQgAAEIFBqAghhqdtP8RCAAAQggBAyByAAAQhAoNQEEMJSt5/iIQABCEAAIWQOQAACEIBAqQkghKVuP8VDAAIQgABCyByAAAQgAIFSE0AIS93+YhQ/URu+2MqePaOaeyXblPouqDa3bi5GlVQBAQikRQAhTIssfjMhMIsIHhz3gmqzsTGTZAgCAQgESQAhDLJtJO0IRBDBDqjKes4MmTMQgMBcBBBC5kaQBKKL4P7yrq82G+uCLJSkIQCB1AkghKkjJkDSBHbXhs42Mhd7+L232mz8roc9phCAQIkIIIQlanYRSt1dG6oZmU2SlnrUc1+12fCx93CNKQQgEDoBhDD0DpYo/9trtaWTWuJEsOZZNpdGPYFhDoEyEUAIy9TtwGv1vC84o1oWywTeetKHQKoEEMJU8eI8KQLxRVA8PpFUE/ADgYISQAgL2tgilRVTBMelynk8NlGkmUAtEEiHAEKYDle8JkQgjgha6dIVzcbMnWYSygY3EIBAEQkghEXsakFqiiOCksYXad+6Zc3mvQXBQBkQgEDKBBDClAHjPh6BmCJ4n5Vdt6I52owXlVEQgEAZCSCEZex6zmuOKYKyshtWNEcvyXl5pAcBCOSMAEKYs4aUPZ34Ish9wbLPHeqHQFwCCGFccoxLnAAimDhSHEIAAhEIIIQRIGGSPgFEMH3GRIAABGYngBAyM3pOABHseQtIAAKlJoAQlrr9vS8+xpsk9ifNs4K9710oGexZvfrp7XblLElnyZpjD8p7wspe12fN1cvHG9eEUhN5JksAIUyWJ948CMR8kwQi6MG4rKZ7Vq9+7H7xs3qpZCK9i7ItXbCy2dhYVmZlrhshLHP3e1h73DdJcCbYw6YFELpVq79E0vSXd8YVo6HlY41t3gMZEDQBhDDo9oWbfJz7gohguP1OKvP9f0DZRcsqMstsRcus1TIrs8xIy2S1TEaHdBPLyFzS3xzZ0I0PxoZHACEMr2fBZxznviAiGHzbYxVw57OOf9wDiyZPlqmcLNnnSHpGLEcRBxnpjv5mY1lEc8wKQgAhLEgjQykjzn1BRDCU7naf5xV6Sd/gwA+eY4092UgnSxrs3mt0DwhhdFZFskQIi9TNnNcS574gIpjzpiaQ3u5Va4dNpe3O9pzwrU/AZWwXXBqNjS7ogQhh0O0LK/kY9wV5k0RYLY6U7YGrApV1RvbZVnIC+JhIAzMwYrFMBpBzGCIVIWzV6jaHtUZKqdpspMIkUvACG8W4L8ibJAoyHw4SPvcow9I8lsbjE3nsSjY5pfKhjxBm07xQosS7L8ibJELp78F5hiJ8nbx5oD7UiZZg3gjhQTA5I0xwdknivmCyPLP2tmewvsZa80bJrrPSkVnHTzSe1QPW2MvabfP5o3Y2rkvUN86CJoAQIoSpTmDuC6aKN1Xnu2r1jRXp/FSDZOHc6Lq21WWV/37856oT1z6YRUhihEUAITyoX9wnSG4Cc18wOZZZe9ozUH9+2+jqrOMmFc9IP25Ln6pU+i7p37FlIim/+CkmAYRwlr5yebT7yc59we4Z9tLD7trQR43MOb3MYd7YRnfK6k4Ze6ex5gea/u+KuVOTfXf27/z23tzmTmK5I5CWELYk9eeu2ogJIYQRQc1hxn3B7vjlYXSrVs/T7/A+I3ND27ZvWFTR9c8YG70hD4zIoTgEUhHC3P81uUD/EMLuJjj3Bbvjl4fRvRRCK/2yIl1vrW5QRTdUxxpb8sCEHIpLIBUhDPn+AlssdTfZJ2r1F1npix5eeF7QA1ZWphn/MXufpM2yut70mRv6d4xsz6pO4kDAEUhFCJ3jUFecscVS/F8Md0l0SkvGfJbZW/G8YHzi6Y1M+Y/Z+420ScZuslN9m6o7t+5IrxI8Q2BhAqkJoQt90DNIk+5N0Eb2X6vNbZsXTi15i4na2hOt2t+azzNbLMXn3qrV3UtNIy+3Zx/R+KyzGJngH7MPaYbwrdi5dSSL/IkBgagEUhXCqElkaTffLzePTsTvxK21tUcuUvt2Dw/sI+oBq1emXTxQv8kau6mvXdm0fHxk3j8+e1UbcSEwTaB0QjjXmWqfNVcvH29cw9SIR6BVG9okGbePZJSD+4JRKGEDAQhkQqCUQpgJ2RIF8V0gw33BEk0OSoVAAAQQwgCalOcUYyyQub7abEQ9c8xz6eQGAQgUhABCWJBG9qoM3wUyk6osO7q59Y5e5UtcCEAAAgcTQAiZE7EJxFggc0G12XArSzkgAAEI5IYAQpibVoSXiOcCme8v0r7asmbz3vAqJeMeEHilpD+VdEIn9rclfUTSp3uQCyELTgAhLHiD0yrPd4GMkc7obza+lFY++C0Ugb+X9PY5KvoHSe8oVLUU03MCCGHPWxBeAp1Ntd0zg0sjZs8CmYigMJM7E7xsAQ6v4syQmZIkAYQwSZol8dWq1d1eoi+KWi4LZKKSwk7STTMuh84FxF0mPRFaEEiKAEKYFMmS+PG9JCqJBTIlmRsJlWkj+uGzKyIozBYmwGRamBEWHQIxLomyQIbZ40sAIfQlhn3XBBDCrhGWx4HvJVEWyJRnbiRYKZdGE4SJq2gEEMJonEpvFeOS6JerzUbk+4ilBwyAaQIslmEuZE4AIcwceXgBY1wSvW+R9h3JM4Ph9TonGfP4RE4aUZY0iiKEr5D0OkkndRrnXvT5j5IuL0sj06yTS6Jp0sX3HAR4oJ6pkRmBIgjhhZLeMgcxJ4juAdzPZka0YIG4JFqwhlIOBCDwCAKhC+FZEc/6PijpPPrvT6BVq49JqkUcySXRiKAwgwAE8kMgdCHcLum4iDjdpZbPRLTFTFLn3uDPo8JglWhUUthBAAJ5IhC6EEZ95sgxv0HSs/MEP++5eF4WZZVo3htKfhCAwKwEyiSEDkDo9WY6jSdqQxdambnuv87MhUuimXaGYBCAQJIEQheG62esFI3CJfR6o9SYmI3H/UG2UUuMOo4gAIGsCYQuDO6xiajvJ3MrSFdnDTjkeK1aPeKl58r6anPr5pBrJXcIQKC8BEIXQte5+R6fmNnZl/MYhd9EjyqE1WajCPPIDw7WEIBAYQgU5QPMPUbhXuQ51wpSHp+IMWURwhjQGAIBCARHoChCOA3enfW9bYYgupWiH+exiXjzEiGMx41REIBAWASKJoRh0c95tghhzhtEehCAQCIEEMJEMBbTCUJYzL5SFQQg8HACCCEzYk4CCCGTAwIQKAMBhLAMXY5ZI0IYExzDIACBoAgghEG1K9tkEcJseRMNAhDoDQGEsDfcg4iKEAbRJpKEAAS6JIAQdgmwyMMRwiJ3l9ogAIFpAgghc2FOAgghkwMCECgDAYSwDF2OWSNCGBMcwyAAgaAIIIRBtSvbZBHCbHkTDQIQ6A0BhLA33IOIihAG0SaShAAEuiSAEHYJsMjDEcIid5faIACBaQIIIXNhTgIIIZMDAhAoAwGEsAxdjlkjQhgTHMMgAIGgCCCEQbUr22QRwmx5Ew0CEOgNAYSwN9yDiIoQBtEmkoQABLokgBB2CbDIwxHCIneX2iAAgWkCCCFzYU4CCCGTAwIQKAMBhLAMXY5ZI0IYExzDIACBoAgghEG1K9tkEcJseRMNAhDoDQGEsDfcg4iKEAbRJpKEAAS6JIAQdgmwyMMRwiJ3l9ogAIFpAgghc2FOAgghkwMCECgDAYSwDF2OWSNCGBMcwyAAgaAIIIRBtSvbZBHCbHkTDQIQ6A0BhLA33IOIihAG0SaShAAEuiSAEHYJsMjDEcIid5faIACBaQIIIXNhTgIIIZMDAhAoAwGEsAxdjlkjQhgTHMMgAIGgCCCEQbUr22QRwmx5Ew0CEOgNAYSwN9yDiIoQBtEmkoQABLokgBB2CbDIwxHCIneX2iAAgWkCCCFzYU4CCCGTAwIQKAMBhLAMXY5ZI0IYExzDIACBoAgghEG1K9tkEcJseRMNAhDoDQGEsDfcg4iKEAbRJpKEAAS6JIAQdgmwyMMRwiJ3l9ogAIFpAgghc2FOAghh+SZHq7Z2nTR1vmRqkpb6ELDSpSuajbN9xmALgTwQQAjz0IWc5oAQ5rQxKaXVqtU3Sjo/jntEMA41xuSFAEKYl07kMA+EMIdNSSmlA2eC7U1x3COCcagxJk8EEMI8dSNnuSCEOWtIium0avXNkp7tGwIR9CWGfR4JIIR57EpOckIIc9KIDNJo1eo/555gBqAJkUsCCGEu25KPpBDCfPQh7SwmasMXW1mvRS6cCabdFfxnSQAhzJJ2YLEQwsAaFiNdRDAGNIYUjgBCWLiWJlcQQpgcyzx6QgTz2BVy6gUBhLAX1AOJiRAG0qgYae6uDZ1tZC72GcrlUB9a2IZEACEMqVsZ54oQZgw8w3ATtfrtVjrSI+T3q82Gj72Ha0wh0FsCCGFv+ec6OkKY6/bETi7e2aDdsKI5eknsoAyEQI4JIIQ5bk6vU0MIe92BdOL7ng3m5JLoOkmvluS+T0q6TtLVkq5JhxJey0QAISxTtz1rRQg9gQVg7ns2mBMRnG/rtwskuZ9zQCA2AYQwNrriD0QIi9djn7PBAERwukFDkrYVr1tUlBUBhDAr0gHGQQgDbNo8Kbdqw+dJ9gMRq8rD4piom4C7e5cbItaFGQQeQQAhZFLMSQAhLM7k8L8kmovFMV+R9IIIXbhD0rIIdphAYFYCCCETAyEs+BzYXRuqGZkxjzLzcDbo0v2JpCdEyBshjAAJk7kJIITMDoSwwHOgI4Lu9UqRX7JrlYuzwdUe9/24NFrgOZxFaQhhFpQDjcGl0UAb10n79lpt6ZSWjAX64Pw5kj4asQMnSvp2RFvMIMA9QuZAdAIIYXRWebN0IjipJe5MsOaTW07OBl3Kn5b0igi5f0HSSyPYYQKBOQlwRsjk4NJoAedAq1b/oqQX+ZSWk8clplN29/2OiJD/eyT9dQQ7TCCAEDIH/AlwRujPLA8jCvBWif8h6YcRWZ4q6dqItphBYFYCnBEyMTgjLNAcmKjVX2Qldzboc4wv0r51y5rNe30GpWh7hqSrIvp/sqS7I9piBgGEkDngR4AzQj9evbbu3Be83WeFqKS8iaDD+FeS/iwCT3fW+LQIdphAYF4CnBEyQTgjLMgciHFf8D4ru25Fc7SZMwTfkPScCDmxUCYCJEwWJoAQLsyotBacEYbT+hiXRPMqgg76/5P0mAj03yYp6pZxEdxhUlYCCGFZOx+hboQwAqQcmMS5JJqjxyQOJniUpFsjYj1B0paItphBYE4CCCGTg0ujgc8B30uiORZB14lXSbo0Ykv4/IoICrP5CTCRmCEIYcBzIMYl0S9Xmw2v5wszxnORpDdGiOnOBN0ZIQcEuiaAEHaNsLgOuDSa797GuCR63yLtOzJHj0nMBnhEUj0CeXdv0N0j5IBA1wQQwq4RFtcBQpjv3vpeEjXSGf3NxpfyXZVsxPzctmpu1SgHBLomgBB2jbC4DqIK4aQqy45ubnVbYnFkRMD3/YKS8n5JdJpcVCF0zw9G3X0mo64QJlQCCGGoncsg71at7p4vG1g4VGV9tbl188J2WCRBoFVbu05quw21ox4hXBL1FUI+u6J2H7sFCTCZFkRUXoNWre7E7dkLEzBvrTZHLlzYDotuCcR5v2Agl0QRwm4nB+NjE0AIY6Mr/sBWrb5R0vkRKr2g2mw4W44UCcR8tVIol0QRwhTnDq7nJ4AQMkPmJNCqDZ8n2Sg7d1xfbTbWgTJdAq3a0CbJ+HAO6ZIoQpju9MH7PAQQQqbHPEIY+V5Us9psDIIyPQJxXq0U2CVRhDC96YPnBQgghEyROQncWlt75CK13dsMFjys7GAON29eMO8QDGKsEHXPIFy6otk4O4T6Dsox6qpRPrsCbG5eU2Yy5bUzOckr6iMUnXQ3VpuNC3KSeiHSiLM4RlLIl6oRwkLM3LCKQAjD6lfm2XoKoSS7eVJ9G3iusPtWxVwck8f3C/rAQAh9aGGbCAGEMBGMxXXiL4T7Wbg3nbtHL5pGusMae0d1bPT64lJKvrIDl6WnLvZdHJPT9wv6AEIIfWhhmwgBhDARjMV1ElMI5wJyr2TdQ/pNydwrYzdP2r7vc/b4G1yds8C3SIrxOEohNjZACIv7cZLbyhDC3LYmH4m1anW3ddoRaWez/8xR9o79ArlfKCUnlO7bIvvQeM43iu4ajzsD7JM9vSJ7npWO9HWY81cr+ZSDEPrQwjYRAghhIhiL66RzhnKJpNNzVOX0meUsKc0Q0oN+amXuNaZ9QGQP/pnVfVmvep0WPyPrVnfW4vINeIXorK2IyIHProigMFuYAJNpYUZYSOos4XfbqD0WILkiEPrimEf8TRKRLp9dEUFhtjABJtPCjLDoEOg8V+he4xNhI26wZUDgvgIsjkEIM5gohJifAELIDPEm4LEHqbdvBkQnUKD7gjOL5h5h9CmAZUIEEMKEQJbNTedVQO7eYeoLacrGNkq9BbsviBBGaTo2qRFACFNDW3zHOV1IU3Tw3zfSeQG8aT5uHzgjjEuOcbEJIISx0TFwmkBnIc153DtMfU5csEj7Liz4oyQIYerTiAAHE0AImROJEjiwoMY9B9deZ2SXWhn3WID7YrVpfNLXT6pydkk2HkAI488TRsYkgBDGBMcwfwLuvqLV1JFGxj0w7sTRfWcF6twox420scCXQWerHCH0/9ViRJcEEMIuATK8ewIH7jUe0nmgvD394ln330s7YlmmBTnjkrlkUuZLJTkDPHgCIYTd/0rhwZMAQugJDPPeE/jN5ddH5jLjjPMRP3Rbl5m5ty9zZ6e9Etyyi9/MXiGEvf8VK10GCGHpWk7BEMg1AYQw1+0pZnIIYTH7SlUQCJUAQhhq5wLOGyEMuHmkDoECEkAIC9jUvJeEECbboTWS3ijJLfiYlHSdpKslXZNsGLxBoLAEEMLCtja/hSGEyfXGvUj1/DncXRDvRavJJYcnCARCACEMpFFFShMhTKabz++c+c3nbUjStmTC4QUChSWAEBa2tfktDCFMpjcflXTOAq7cBtUbkgmHFwgUlgBCWNjW5rcwhDCZ3rQk9S/g6g5Jy5IJhxcIFJYAQljY1ua3MIQwmd5E/eV9kqSfJBMSLxAoJIGov0t8dhWy/b0pismUDPeov7wsmkmGN16KSyDq7xKfXcWdA5lXxmRKBvnXJZ0S0RViGBEUZqUkgBCWsu29LRohTIb/yyV9xsMVYugBC9NSEUAIS9XufBSLECbTh8dJ2iupz8PdyyRd4WGPKQTKQAAhLEOXc1YjQphcQ9wZoTszjHqMSjqhswNN1DHYQaDoBBDConc4h/UhhMk1xffyqIv8bkl/m1wKeIJA8AQQwuBbGF4BCGGyPZtvm7XZIrlHKU6U5J5D5IAABCSEkFmQOQGEMHnkvmLodqX50+TTwCMEgiSAEAbZtrCTRgjT6Z+vGD5X0n+kkwpeIRAUAYQwqHYVI1mEML0+XibplRHdOxF0YsgBgbITQAjLPgN6UD9CmB70FZK+JykqY3d51F0m5YBAmQkghGXufo9qj/oh3aP0gg/7fyX9n4hVuAUzbuEMe5FGBIZZIQkghIVsa76LQgjT7c+jJH3H460T7lEK90gFBwTKSOAdkt4fsXA+uyKCwmxhAkymhRl1a/EaSZ+M6GSy85C9e9ieAwJlIfBqSedKGvYomM8uD1iYzk+AyZTNDLlO0vqIody2a277NQ4IFJ3ASzsCuC5GoXx2xYDGkNkJMJmymRluRejXPEKxcMYDFqbBEXhBRwCf10XmfHZ1AY+hDyfAZMpuRnxK0oaI4e7tvNaJS6QRgWEWBIHlkt4l6XUJZMtnVwIQcXGAAJMpu5lwrKRtkpZEDLlJ0h9KmopojxkE8kzgzZ2FYE9OKEk+uxICiRuEMOs58BeS/twj6D9IcivpOCAQKoE/6Aig+6MuieNqSedJui0JZ/iAAGeE2c+Bx0vaIqnqEdq91eKzHvaYQiAPBJ7UEcC3JpTMDyW553I/npA/3EDg1wS4vJD9ZHiDpA95hHUfAO6vabdLDQcE8k7gKZLOkOQuhbrdlZI4PibpfEl3J+EMHxA4mABC2Js58WlJr/AI/RVJp3vYYwqBrAm8UNKZHRH8nYSCXyvpXyS5y6EcEEiNAEKYGtp5HbsFA26j7WM8wrs3WlzgYY8pBNImcFxH+NwZ4LMSDLa5I4DumVoOCKROACFMHfGcAdwzVP/uGd6dFbqzQw4I9IrAE2eI3x8lnMRIRwAvTdgv7iAwLwGEsLcT5M8k/ZVHCu4+obtf6O4bckAgSwLuDzd35ue+npBw4Lsk/Y2kf07YL+4gEIkAQhgJU6pGn5fktpqKergVpG4lKQcE0ibgLt1P3/erpRTsE5L+mschUqKL20gEEMJImFI1OqJzv9BnhZ17ttA9Y8gBgaQJLJ1x5ue2QkvraHQE8EtpBcAvBKISQAijkkrXzt378/lAcLvNuEukbvcZDggkQeDkGQKY1O4vs+X1q85lUHcpdF8SieMDAt0SQAi7JZjceLcq1D0rFfVw+5CeIsntS8oBgTgE+iW9uHP5sx7HgeeYKzsi6LYa5IBAbggghLlpxf5EvijpRR4pfVSSe1MFBwR8CDjxm/6Kuvetj/+Dbd1ryD4j6eJunDAWAmkRQAjTIhvPr9t6zT1feKTHcPdsoTub5IDAfAQGZojfMzNA5fYCvarz5bYV5IBAbgkghPlrzUsk+T5IjBjmr495yOjRM8QvzYUv07XaGeLnLoM+mAcI5ACBhQgghAsR6s3P/1LSezxDI4aewApsfuIMAXx6BnVunyGA7ImbAXBCJEsAIUyWZ5LevirpVE+HbMPmCaxA5ofPEL/1GdT1sxni97UM4hECAqkRQAhTQ9u1Y7d3o7tf6Hbz9zkQQx9a4ds+d4YAPi6Dcr4hyV32dPf/9mYQjxAQSJ0AQpg64q4CuB1k3Go73wMx9CUWjr37nXUvu3Vf7lnSoQxSn5hx9uf2A+WAQKEIIIT5b6e79/feGGkihjGg5XSIe8B9Wvzcd59VxXFLmpwhfu7s76G4jhgHgbwTQAjz3qED+bmNud0G3b7Hf0p6vyT3nSMsAm5vz2nxc/eKs/pddRs1TF/6bIWFjGwhEI9AVr9c8bJj1EwCTtDcHqNxjoskvVPSA3EGMyYTAos7wvccSe71RsdmEvVAkJ/MOPtz96U5IFAqAghhWO2+UNJbYqZ8Z+cS6yUxxzMseQJP64ifE77TJD0m+RDzevz6DAH8acaxCQeB3BBACHPTisiJfEjSGyJbP9LQLXU/V9IdXfhgaHwCazpnfO5y5/Hx3cQeuWuG+LHnZ2yMDCwSAYQwzG5+TNLrukz97yR9SpL7YORIj8ChktwjDk743Flfmm92mKsKt8PL9HZn7ns7vXLxDIHwCCCE4fVsOmO3gfHZCaTvdgL5pKTLeC4sAZoHXLg9Y53oOfFzjzj06tjaEUC3+MXt/ckBAQjMQgAhDHtauGcMk3xb/Y2dNwR8ln0iI0+MVZLchtbu+/S/D4s8OnnDu2ec/X0zefd4hEDxCCCE4ff0c5JelkIZ7hLa5Z0P1RTcB+fSidvBgueELw+Hu/TpRG/68ufP85AUOUAgFAIIYSidmj/Pd0l6t6SlKZTjHqx2l03dWWJZzjDydpY3W1v3SNo04+vHKfQelxAoBQGEsDhtdnuTOjF8RYolud1F/uugL7f58kL/7/+lmFM3rvN8ljdbXZs7wue+39BN4YyFAAR+QwAhLN5scJdJ3RniYPFKK11F7hKnewvJ9Jnf7aUjQMEQyIAAQpgB5B6EeFRHDN0ZotuxhCMcAt85SPzY4zOc3pFpoAQQwkAbFzHteudy6RkR7THrDYFrJV3TOfO7tTcpEBUC5SWAEJaj96+R9MeSTi5Hubmv8q6O8E1f9vxF7jMmQQgUmABCWODmzlLacZJO73y5RwE4siPQmCF+O7ILSyQIQGAhAgjhQoSK+/NTJLlLpk4Ye7HtV3HJHqjsh5LcS2zdWZ+77One8MABAQjkkABCmMOm9CCll0pyX04UF/Ugfugh3QKXcUnNzpf7N29zCL2r5Lvw5fMAABuwSURBVF8aAghhaVodqdBHd7ZsO0vSSZFGlMvIPQ/pxO5g0ZsqFwaqhUCxCCCExepnktW4d+U5QXR7mWb5ktgka+jG1/dnETw2ru6GKGMhkFMCCGFOG5OztA7pbN/mtnD73Rn/dv8d5f/l/XLrbGd57NeZs0lIOskR2DNYX2OteaNk11lp0spe12fN1cvHG+5+dukOhLB0LadgCECgzAR21eobK9L5szFoSxesbDY2lo0PQli2jlMvBCBQWgJ7BurPbxtdPR+AitHQ8rHGtjJBQgjL1G1qhQAESk1gd23o/UbmHfNBMDKX9DdHNpQJFEJYpm5TKwQgUFoCEwPD51hjP7oQACPd0d9sLFvIrkg/RwiL1E1qgQAEIDALgagiOD202myUShtKVSy/IRCAAATKRmBioP56a/QRn7oRQh9a2EIAAhCAQG4JTNTq77TS3/kmiBD6EsMeAhCAAARyR2DXYP1vKnb/S7q9Dmvte1eMj77Pa1DgxlwaDbyBpA8BCEDgYAKtweHPydqXeZOxend1vPG33uMCH4AQBt5A0ocABCAwk0BroL5FRmu9qVi9rTre+ID3uAIMQAgL0ERKgAAEIOAItGr1myU9y5eGsXpT/3jjIt9xRbFHCIvSSeqAAARKS+B7g4NP6bOLt0h6ui8EY83r+8dHPuY7rkj2CGGRukktEIBA6QhM1IZOsDJus2y3Ib7XYYx9S//Y6D95DSqgMUJYwKZSEgQgUA4CEwNDL2sb8xkT54XaJV0YM9vMQAjL8ftClRCAQMEItGr110r6eJyyyvqWiblYIYRxZhFjIAABCPSQQGug/lYZ/WOcFKzseSuaox+MM7aoYxDConaWuiAAgUISaA0Ov1fWXhCnOGP06v6xxmVxxhZ5DEJY5O5SGwQgUBgCrcGhc401b7HSylhFVewLqztG530XYSy/BRiEEBagiZQAAQgUl8BPTjzxMffe/9CFsnpNzCptxZqTlo+PfCvm+MIPQwgL32IKhAAEQiWwqzY0VJG5UNIJMWv4qaxdVx0f/W7M8aUYhhCWos0UmSaBPQP1508Z+wIj8wcujpW9rs+aq5ePN9yzXRwQiEWgNTD8Ch14ke6hsRxIu9u27w9Wjm/5UczxpRmGEJam1RSaBoFdtfrGinT+bL5Zop4G8XL43F2r/4WR/ryLarfc1zd18prt2+/vwkdphiKEpWk1hSZNYM9gfU3banQ+vxWjoeVjjW1Jx8ZfMQm0Vg0/VRX7L5Ke30WF11SbjRd0Mb50QxHC0rWcgpMiMFEbvtjKnj2fPyNzSX9zZENSMfFTXAJ7Boee07bmckmHxa3SSJf2Nxvzzsm4vos8DiEscnepLVUCE7X67VY6cn4h1B39zcayVBPBefAEunlAfkbxH6g2G28LHkYPCkAIu4Deqq1ZZ9T3asmus9IkiyS6gBng0FatbqOkXW02+D2LAqqENle85CV9tdb3P22kP+6i/KaMLqqONT7ZhY9SD+UXNGb7WSQRE1yBhiGEBWpmD0q57bjhVVNte6Wk/i7Cv67abHyii/EMlYQQxpgG84ngtDsWScQAG9gQhDCwhuUo3dZg/U9k1Y2A/cBUzJn9O0a256isYFNBCD1b554ZaxstuE0RiyQ8wQZojhAG2LQepzwxUD/DGv2lpKNjp2J0dX//EWeYL3xhKrYPBj6MAELoOSEmavVrrHTaQsOMWCSxEKPQf44Qht7B7PLfNTj0nIo175N0fDdRjTHv6x8beW83Phj7SAIIocesiHo26FwihB5gAzVFCANtXIZpf2+wvqZPeq+sun2u72fW2nNWjI9elWH6pQmFEHq0enetfqORfi/KEC6NRqEUtg1CGHb/0sx+T224OiW9xyzwnGmUHKx0g51qb1j5nW23RbHHxp8AQujBLOoH3wGX7fXV5rbNHu4xDYxA1PnA4xOBNbaLdCdWnfAkVR56p5V5s6QlXbjqDDUfrjZH3ti9HzzMRwAh9JgfUT/42GPSA2qgplG2V5suDSEMtMkeabf6n/dbesxP3ypbeZNkn+IxdHZTqwdk7NurzdEPd+0LBwsSQAgXRPQbg6hCyAefB9QATaM8PjOzLOZDgE32SHmiNvQ6a/QmWXOsx7A5TY20rWLs258xNnpDEv7wsTABhHBhRr+2QAg9YBXU1GfBFGeEBZ0EnbImBof/p6x9o424biAKDStdulj7zlvWbN4bxR6bZAgghB4cEUIPWAU13V0b+qiROcenvElVlh3d3HqHzxhs80tg90D9+cbYt0tmXYJZfrdidNHyscZHEvSJq4gEEMKIoJwZQugBq6CmrVq9FWNLrL2mrT/u39m4rqBYSlGW21tYMucnLIA/lNVFj7EPXHT4zp2/LAXIHBaJEHo0BSH0gFVQ05hCOE2DfSEDnBcHXo+k/52wAP5CshdNmSUXHTV2010BYilUygihRzsRQg9YBTWNc2l0Jgq30UJb9oIVzdFLCoqoEGW1BgefKC0511i7YaFXbfkXbD5sK+aiFTu23uo/lhFpEEAIPagihB6wCmoaZ7HMbCgQxHxOkD2Da062tu/lVvblkhYnnOXlqpiLqjtGtibsF3ddEkAIPQAihB6wCmw6MTD8QWuse2C668MJopX+klfpdI3S28HEqjXHtPsqxxqrYyRzjJU91kiJv0TZStcYq4uq442veyfJgEwIIIQemBFCD1gFM91VGxoyMuuN1XoZ/VHS5R0QRPt+HqBOmqx08zOf+ehDljxqlTFm1VRbA8ZolWRWSfbRyUf7jUdrdaORvag6PnpFmnHw3T0BhNCDYVQhtLIbuAfkATaHpntWr36snepbL2vWq6L11tpEHpZeqNQDl0zNhSuaIx9cyJafP5zAXatXP+EB23d0e8ocbU37aBlztLHmKCt7RJasjDQ6Jfvxlc3Rj2cZl1jxCSCEHuyiCiFvnvCAmiPT1uDwM+XO+Gx7vYxZL+lxPUzPrSrcLlvZLmNH1DZbqjtHftjDfHIXujVYP15trZXZ/2oj9/XU3iZpbzLSJ/pZCNXbNsSIjhB6QNtdq98W+R6C0WurY41PerjHtAcE3CbJpjJ1VtvYl8lqbQ9S8Al5m5X9hpH5xpKpJd844jvf+rnP4JBtW6uGn6qKnRY816eu3uuXMItNVvrEimbjswn7xV1GBBBCD9BuSyVr7b9GHWLa7WP7d267Oao9dtkR6GyafZaRzrLSYdlFTi7SgcuouqUifbcte0uf9N3/bj94y0BAD2bfPjR0+OQ++2RT0eHtdt/hxuhwa+2T3fcD/9aTJR0uKdX7eXG6Yoy+ZmU+WR0b+bc44xmTHwIIoWcvJmr1cSt3sz3Ssa3abAxFssQoEwJ7jhs6sz1VOUvGvjiTgAQpHAFrzFVGU5dWx7Z9pXDFlbQghNCz8a2BoVfImE9HHma13ch8rH985GORx2CYKIHpy59W1p39Zf+HidV2Ga1OtCicZUrASj+TNZdbTV2+cnxbI9PgBEudAEIYA3FroL5FxvN+EoIYg3R3Q/Jy+dO9hmliYPgcK3sOgthdT7MebaVxSZe3zeLL2Qota/rZxUMIY7DeVRt6XUUm3hkeghiDePQhdt26RRM//+WZUuWlebn8OfN9hAhi9F72ztLcZWXHZHT5irFG5DUBvcuXyN0SQAhjEmwN1i+T1StjDpeMPjV1/+Lzjtp10y9i+2DgrwnsqQ0NtY15sazOlFTNAM0+SUuixJntxbwIYhRy6du4BUcyZoe1dqeM+W67Mnnzyu3bv5d+ZCLkiQBCGLMbdz7r+Mf9avHUJhN94cwskcxNFWPPWz7W2BYzjVIPcxsj2/biM43ZL36nZADDPcd3nTH6pp0y16li74wSc7431COIUQgmZtPqiN4OyYwt6Zu8+cjt23+cmHccBUsAIeyidQfeT1bZ1IULN/Snktn44L72lcfcMnp3l75KMbw1MHyKqdgz7YGzvyemWrSxO6zVdZWKvvnAA7+87phbbnFngvuPqBsszCeE076cIMroVVb26B4/yJ8qzoyc7zVW35ExN1vZmxe1K9/5bd1/M+/7y4h+gGEQwi6bNjFYf5O1+qcu3bjh/yWZK2XtlWzO+3Cae1avfnp7srJWxqy10u+ZtFd+Wn3NGPNN2zbXVXdu3TFXb5MUwpkxdh+39mhNTR1tjDlKMkdb2SEjrUxgjhXRxYOSRqw0ImNGzJRG2IGniG1OtyaEMAG+rVrd7Sn42gRc7XdhpVFjdaXp67uyf8eWiaT8huLne6vqyxb3aa1tm7V2/+pcW089d6u7rbGfN5XK56K+JictIZyt1taqYbeV2OmSXiRjj0qdR04DWOlWyYxUrN3aNnZkRXO0mdNUSSsgAghhQs1qDQ6dK+lcWZPk5sz7jHRl25grV4yNXJlQqrlzM3Hc8f12qt3ZM9KeJLnX4mRzGKMbrTWfb/dNfn7l9u0/9YmapRDOzGvX6tVP6JsyK63tW2mMXWllj7IyKwM9a3SXmvfK2L1qm70y2mtl91ZUuWf//zN2r53s2yvZvQ9O/mLvzEvTPr3CFgLzEUAIE54fe2rD51nZc620ImHX90gat7I7ja3sXLSoMrps+5YgV7fdtmrNyinTd6Ix+n0r+/uSlifMaiF398voc2qbz1fHR/5jIeO5ft4rIYybL+MgAIHZCSCEKc2M/WeI1rxb0tNTCuHc7hdH95aCtjWjUl9j5fiWH6UYL5br244bdu+B+33JnmTkxG///pG9OMYl8/nFbfu5I3c2bu82AYSwW4KMh0A+CCCEKfehNVj/E1l9IuUwuJ+fwBdkzBVJb46MEDLtIFAMAghhBn3cXRuqGZnPSHpWBuEIcWDB0a6KNVfITl2R1htAEEKmGgSKQQAhzKiPreHh3zEP2n+20qsyClnKMEb6Ulv6wo+WHnrF+s2bJ9OEgBCmSRffEMiOAEKYHev9kVq1+vn798BMdnVpxlXkLtxtcmd/mrqiOr5tLKvsEMKsSBMHAukSQAjT5Tun91Zt+HQje6aV3HvxHtWjNIINa6Sft6UtVrri0N/uu+JpW7b8KutiEMKsiRMPAukQQAjT4RrZ64FdU/pe7PbLdLumRB5YMkMre5estsiYhlGl8ai+hxpP2b79/l5iQAh7SZ/YEEiOAEKYHMuuPbVqa9fJtN1l0zMl+5SuHYbtYI+VudGYdsOYSqN/x8j2vJWDEOatI+QDgXgEEMJ43FIddXuttnTS/NaZ1toXG9khyaS7sXSq1UR2frNkbnBnfRXZxvLxxu7II3tkiBD2CDxhIZAwAYQwYaBpuJs4bni1tbYmawcl1SRTC/2+opFGrdWNMuaGKbNv9KixsbvSYJemT4QwTbr4hkB2BBDC7FgnGsmJo6a0um3aq401q2W0OtEAyTu7wUo3GmtumHpg0ZYivJAYIUx+kuARAr0ggBD2gjoxC0EAISxEGykCAkIImQQQiEkAIYwJjmEQyBkBhDBnDSGdcAgghOH0ikwhMB8BhJD5AYGYBBDCmOAYBoGcEUAIc9YQ0gmHAEIYTq/IFAKcETIHIJACAYQwBai4hEAPCHBG2APohCwGAYSwGH2kCggghMwBCMQkgBDGBMcwCOSMAEKYs4aQTjgEEMJwekWmEOAeIXMAAikQQAhTgIpLCPSAAGeEPYBOyGIQQAiL0UeqgABCyByAQEwCCGFMcAyDQM4IIIQ5awjphEMAIQynV2QKAe4RMgcgkAIBhDAFqLiEQA8IcEbYA+iELAaBqELYli5Y2WxsLEbVVAGB4hFACIvXUyrKiEBUIXTpGOmM/mbjSxmlRhgIQMCDAELoAQtTCMwkMFGr326lI6NQsTLfWNEc+cMotthAAALZEkAIs+VNtAIR2F0bOtvIXBy5JGtfWR0f/UxkewwhAIFMCCCEmWAmSFEJtGpDmySzLlJ9Vlur443jI9liBAEIZEYAIcwMNYGKSGDXQP2MitFVUWszRm/uH2v8c1R77CAAgfQJIITpMyZCwQnsqtU3VqTzI5Vpdbfp6/v9/h1bJiLZYwQBCKROACFMHTEBykCgVat/W1LEy5724mpz9DVl4EKNEAiBAEIYQpfIMfcEWrWhl0vGZyHMS6vNxhdyXxgJQqAEBBDCEjSZErMhsLtW/7qRTokYbezBfYeedMwtm/87oj1mEIBASgQQwpTA4rZ8BFrHDb1AbfOV6JXbv642R98T3R5LCEAgDQIIYRpU8VlaAq2B+idk9CdRAbTbOmnlzsaNUe2xgwAEkieAECbPFI8lJrCnNlxty35L0pOiYTDXVpsjp0azxQoCEEiDAEKYBlV8lppAa6D+Nhn9Q1QIxth39I+NRraP6hc7CEAgGgGEMBonrCDgRcBnxxkjtY2xpywfG/2mVxCMIQCBRAgghIlgxAkEHk5g1+Ca51Vs5d8jczFmx28vtqc8tdH4WeQxGEIAAokQQAgTwYgTCDySQKtW/7CkcyOzMfpUdawReaFNZL8YQgAC8xJACJkgEEiJwG2DJxwxZSfdwpmnRg3BXqRRSWEHgeQIIITJscQTBB5BYGKg/r+sUeRNto3RAxWjU56xg0cqmE4QyIoAQpgVaeKUlsDuWv0SI706MgCjrUsPXXzKE2+66ReRx2AIAQjEJoAQxkbHQAhEI3Brvf74xfv0NSutiTZCMkYf6R9rRL+/GNUxdhCAwCMIIIRMCghkQOC2waGTptrm6zI6JHI4q3dXxxt/G9keQwhAIBYBhDAWNgZBwJ9Aqzb0Bsl8yGekseb1/eMjH/MZgy0EIOBHACH044U1BLoi0KoNf0iyb/ByYu3LquOjV3iNwRgCEIhMACGMjApDCHRP4PZ16w556N773euaTvLwdr+VedGK5sh/eozBFAIQiEgAIYwICjMIJEXge4P1NX1WX5P0eA+fPzIVc3r/jpHtHmMwhQAEIhBACCNAwgQCSROYqNVfbaVLPP3e3J5qn77yO9tu8xyHOQQgMA8BhJDpAYEeEZio1f/CSn/uE94Y3dhn971wWbN5r884bCEAgbkJIITMDgj0kMDEYP0j1ur1XilYXV0db7zQawzGEIDAnAQQQiYHBHpMYPfA0L8ZY17sk4aRLu1vNs72GYMtBCAwOwGEkJkBgRwQ8Hl/4W/StRdWm6NvzUH6pACBoAkghEG3j+SLQsCuW7do4t77xyQd41OTseZ9/eMj7/UZgy0EIPBwAgghMwICOSEwseqEJ6ky2bTSk31SMlYf6R9nX1IfZthCYCYBhJD5AIEcEdh17OqjKn19OyUt9krL2iuXPnrJBt5Y4UUNYwjsJ4AQMhEgkDMCrcH68bL6doy0blgy1d5wBM8ZxkDHkDITQAjL3H1qzy2B3bX6aUa6JkaCty5qVzYs27l1JMZYhkCglAQQwlK2naJDINAaGH6FjP10jFx/WrHasHy8EUdIY4RjCATCJoAQht0/si84gd2DQ2821nwwTpkVa16zfHzk4jhjGQOBMhFACMvUbWoNkkCrVj9f0sY4yRvpXf3Nxt/FGcsYCJSFAEJYlk5TZ9AEWrWhl0vmM3GKMDJ/398ceWecsYyBQBkIIIRl6DI1FoLA7lVrh02lvTVOMW5LtuVLD32t2bx5Ms54xkCgyAQQwiJ3l9oKR2DimKGn2UXmB3EKM9K/L+qbeu2R27f/OM54xkCgqAQQwqJ2lroKS2B81apHHVo5ZFzSct8ijTRaqZjXPmPHiHtonwMCEOCBeuYABMIl0Bqsf01Wz/WtwEh3GGNfu3xs9Ju+Y7GHQBEJcEZYxK5SU2kItGpDF0nmjTEK/qW1+jPbbn+VN97HoMeQQhFACAvVToopI4Fdg0Nvr1jz9zFrn5LsV42tfLVvSfsry0ZH747ph2EQCJYAQhhs60gcAr8hMFEbOtvKdPvw/P2Svmqkr07+avFVR+266RcwhkAZCCCEZegyNZaCQGtw7Qtl219OqNifS+arMvpy/9jIVUZqJ+QXNxDIHQGEMHctISEIxCewZ2D499rGuj1GHxvfy8NHGqO7Zc3VU2bqiyvHtl2blF/8QCAvBBDCvHSCPCCQEIHW4PAz1baXyWh1Qi5/7cbIfN+q/cW+irnqGTsaNybtH38Q6AUBhLAX1IkJgZQJ3D40dPjkQ5VPSfZ5qYWyulvGjEntpmTGHqz0jR2zY8tEavFwDIGUCCCEKYHFLQR6TeDmZz5zyW8tefSnJL08s1xmiqOp7FhkzbZlza13ZBafQBCIQQAhjAGNIRAIicDugfo/GaM39Sznjjga2R1TVtv7puy2/ptH7+xZPgSGwEEEEEKmBARKQGBXrb6xTzrVSkO5KNfqbmu0w1i7ra9P2/bZye1HjY3dlXZutx0zfJiW6LCpKR0u6TBjdFhb7cOMMYfJ6jArHW6kw9zPJE1I9hbJfqDa3LY57dzw3zsCCGHv2BMZApkTmKitOVGqOEE8TdJA5gkEGtBK71rBex0D7d7CaSOECzPCAgKFJDAxMLxexp0lWieKRxeyyASLqhidtXys8a8JusRVTggghDlpBGlAoJcEWgP15xqZU63ZL4reb7XoZe7ZxTbXVpsjp2YXj0hZEUAIsyJNHAgEQMBKlYlVQ6cZY061FZ0mq6cFkHZmKVabDT4zM6OdXSCamh1rIkEgKAK3r1t3yEP3/eo0I3uq7P57im4BSZmPiWqzUS0zgKLWjhAWtbPUBYEECbSGh3/H7rOnGWtOlewJkp6RoPtAXNmvVJujpweSLGl6EEAIPWBhCgEIHCCwZ6C+oi1bk1FNUs3K1Iz05GLzaa/nMYpidhghLGZfqQoCmRNwe5wa2TXWHhDHztfvZp5ICgF5fCIFqDlyiRDmqBmkAoGiEfjeccOrKlNabUx7jaw5br84Gh0STp3m2oqxn+axiXA6FidThDAONcZAAAKxCbQG1gzKVFZbozUVq9VWWhPbmf/AfZL2yuoeY3RPW2avMfYetXWPjN3bNvaeRZXF99z/YHvvsTeP3OPvnhEhEkAIQ+waOUMAAhCAQGIEEMLEUOIIAhCAAARCJIAQhtg1coYABCAAgcQIIISJocQRBCAAAQiESAAhDLFr5AwBCEAAAokRQAgTQ4kjCEAAAhAIkQBCGGLXyBkCEIAABBIjgBAmhhJHEIAABCAQIgGEMMSukTMEIAABCCRGACFMDCWOIAABCEAgRAIIYYhdI2cIQAACEEiMAEKYGEocQQACEIBAiAQQwhC7Rs4QgAAEIJAYAYQwMZQ4ggAEIACBEAkghCF2jZwhAAEIQCAxAghhYihxBAEIQAACIRJACEPsGjlDAAIQgEBiBBDCxFDiCAIQgAAEQiSAEIbYNXKGAAQgAIHECCCEiaHEEQQgAAEIhEgAIQyxa+QMAQhAAAKJEUAIE0OJIwhAAAIQCJEAQhhi18gZAhCAAAQSI4AQJoYSRxCAAAQgECIBhDDErpEzBCAAAQgkRgAhTAwljiAAAQhAIEQCCGGIXSNnCEAAAhBIjABCmBhKHEEAAhCAQIgE/j88Mh+k16/e0gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

```
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(url);
  Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(512, 512);
  tex.LoadImage( imageBytes );
  GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
```

Comment: Do you already have a way to get just the base64 part (`iVBOR...ggg==`) into a string variable?

Comment: It starts out as a string variable with all the extra bits, I could probably remove the 'data:image' parts relatively easily. Other tutorials on similar issues convert into byte arrays but 'Convert.FromBase64String' is giving me the error: invalid length',

Comment: Be very careful that you're not including these characters at the beginning: `data:image/png;base64,` especially make sure that the comma at the end isn't included in the base64

Comment: For now I can just manually input the url as a string without the 'data:image/png' stuff. Is there a way I can convert this into a image within unity?

Comment: yes, there is a way, but it has to be input correctly. Have your code `Debug.Log` the string out before it tries to decode it, and paste that here in a comment.

Comment: The string that is logged is the string I put above. When I try to convert this string  without 'data:image/png;base64,'  into a bytearray using Convert.FromBase64String I get an error 'formatException: invalid length'

Comment: If that's the string that is logged, then you aren't cutting off the beginning piece of the string properly. You need to remove the first 22 characters.

Comment: I have just tried doing it with another base64 image, I still have the same issue. I would send copy and paste the code but it has too many characters. The base 64 starts and ends the same though. so it starts with "iVB...' and ends with"=="

Comment: And when I put the exact string into a online base64 image converter, it works. So I am really struggling to understand why its too long for Base64String

Comment: I have just edited my post to include the exact code I am using

Comment: Try doing `Debug.Log(string.Format("base64 string length: {0}", url.Length))` **immediately before** the `FromBase64String` call. It should show `base64 string length: 1012`. If it outputs anything else, your url string is not written correctly in source code or it is being overwritten somewhere, maybe by the unity inspector.

Comment: It was the unity inspector overriding it! Wow I feel like an idiot Hahak thank you so much for the help!

Comment: A little concerned why the `Debug.Log` check earlier didn't show that but I'm glad a fix was found.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to convert it from Base64URL to regular Base64. Then, once you have the `byte[]` from using `FromBase64String(base64);`, you just need to create a `Texture2D` then `LoadImage` it into the texture:

```
byte[] imageBytes = FromBase64String(base64);
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(512, 512);
tex.LoadImage(imageAsset.bytes);
GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
```

Comment: When I try your code with 'base64' substituted for the image's base64 representation (without data:image/png;base64), I get an error 'formatException: invalid length'